# Trocar imagem em javascript após clique

Tags: javascript

Como troco uma imagem usando JavaScript?

Fiz esse código aqui mas não deu certo.

**arquivo HTML**

```
  <a href="passo1.html" target="janela">
     <img id="passo1" class="passo" src="img/passo_color1.png" style="float:left">
  </a>
```

**arquivo JS**

```
            teste = document.querySelector("#passo1").addEventListener('click', function(){
teste.src = "img/passo_color.jpg";});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para começar, eis um exemplo funcional do que você quer: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nr6LpLqb/)

Observe que para referenciar o próprio elemento você deve usar 'this':

```
document.querySelector("#passo1").addEventListener('click', function(){
    this.src = "img/passo_color.jpg";
});
```

Além disso você está com dois eventos 'on click'. Ao deixar o `href="passo1.html"` na sua tag `<a>` você está dizendo que ao clicar nesse elemento o usuário deve ser redirecionado para o link em questão (ao deixar target="janela" ao menos vai abrir outra janela e não redirecionar a própria janela para outro link).

No meu exemplo eu deixei sem, mas se for esse efeito mesmo que você quer, mudar a imagem e abrir uma nova janela então assim seja.

Comment: No caso esse target é para um iframe que vem logo abaixo da imagem, conforme eu clico no imagem, o coteúdo do iframe muda.. a ideia é essa... mas vou tentar fazer aqui com o q vc mandou... vi que no JSFiddle funcionou !!! ;)

Comment: Hmmm, agora faz muito mais sentido.